# Check if window is losing focus

Tags: c++, winapi

Which notification message do you receive if any window is losing focus?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`WM_KILLFOCUS`. In case you care, `wParam` will be the handle of the window that's receiving the focus.

Answer (score 3):

[WM_ACTIVATE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms646274%28VS.85%29.aspx)

Comment: WM_ACTIVATE, but check the WParam... should be WA_INACTIVE.