# How to close app when mouse click outside the window?

Tags: c++, winapi

I'm creating a `Win32` single window application. What I want is the application to close when the user clicks anywhere **outside** the app window.

I've read somewhere that to do that one can handle the [`WM_KILLFOCUS`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/inputdev/wm-killfocus) message. But that does not seems to work (the `WM_KILLFOCUS` is't even received!).

Here is the code of my message loop:

```
LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc(HWND hWnd, UINT message,
    WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam) {
    HDC          hdc;
    PAINTSTRUCT  ps;

    switch (message) {
    case WM_PAINT:
        hdc = BeginPaint(hWnd, &ps);
        OnPaint(hdc);
        EndPaint(hWnd, &ps);
        return 0;
    case WM_DESTROY:       
        PostQuitMessage(0);
        return 0;

    case WM_COMMAND: {
        switch (LOWORD(wParam)) {
        case WM_KILLFOCUS:
            MessageBoxA(NULL, "Focus will be gone", "WM_KILLFOCUS", MB_OK);
            DestroyWindow(hWnd);
            return TRUE;
        }
    }
   ...
    }
}
```

Comment: not `EN_KILLFOCUS`, but `WM_KILLFOCUS`. and how this related to caption ?

Comment: Please edit the title of your question to match the question itself.  Mouse tracking is not bitmap drawing.

Comment: @RbMm - Sorry, I've just corrected the title:-)

Comment: @DaveS Of course,;-), Sorry just corrected the title:-)

Comment: @RbMm WM_KILLFOCUS ALSO doesn't work! Please help!

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/inputdev/wm-activate

Comment: or the APP version if you have more than one window in your own app, like dialogs -  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winmsg/wm-activateapp

Comment: WM_KILLFOCUS of course work, if correct use it

Comment: @RbMin - if the app has no elements that can take keyboard focus, will it ever have gotten focus to be lost?  Not sure myself, my apps generally have at least something that does take focus.

Comment: `WM_KILLFOCUS` needs to be in the outer switch, not under `WM_COMMAND`.

Comment: @DaveS yes, not need any elements ( child windows) inside window. Window get focus message after visible activated. And lost focus when we click outside

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As described in an answer to the question [Check if window is losing focus](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2439556/check-if-window-is-losing-focus) you could listen for the [WM_ACTIVATE message](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/windows/win32/inputdev/wm-activate) as it is

> Sent to both the window being activated and the window being deactivated.

But I don't think this is how an Windows application should behave. There are going to be times when your application loses focus for reasons other than the user clicking somewhere else and they may not have wanted to exit the application yet. It seems to me you are trying to recreate the interaction provided by website dialog boxes, where clicking outside of them can close the dialog.

The [Windows Application Development - Best Practices for User Experience](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/apps/get-started/best-practices#user-experience-ux) recommends

> When applications adhere to Windows styles and standard Windows behaviors, users don't have to re-learn interaction patterns.

I think you may confuse users if you close the application when it loses focus.